# How to get an array in Django posted via Ajax

Tags: ajax, django, jquery, python-2.7

When I try to send an array to Django via Ajax (jQuery)

**JavaScript code:**

```
new_data = ['a','b','c','d','e'];
$.get('/pythonPage/', {'data': new_data},function(data){});
```

and I try to read the array:

**Python:**

```
request.GET.get("data[]")
```

I get only the last array value:

```
'e'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You're looking for the `QueryDict`'s `getlist`

```
request.GET.getlist('data')
request.GET.getlist('data[]')
request.GET.getlist('etc')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist

Comment: Had a similar problem but using the `POST` method, where the final line that worked for me was `request.POST.getlist('data[]')`

Comment: `'selected = request.GET.getlist['selected[]']  TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '__getitem__'` I get this error... But i have an array of stings like ["one","two","three"]

Comment: @nidHi you need `request.GET.getlist('selected[]')` instead of `request.GET.getlist['selected[]']`

Comment: request.GET.getlist('data[]') worked for me in Django 2.0

Comment: I owe you one mate, i was looking for this and it was driving me crazy

Comment: not in django but in wsgi I had to extract my ajax list data (with keys) somehow, so I managed to loop through the data list (stripe products) via the count that was passed in as well... then doing something like
     productid = post.getvalue("productlist[0][id]")

Answer (score 6):

Quite old question but let me show you full working code for this. (Good for newbie :)

**In your template**

```
data = {
    'pk' : [1,3,5,10]
}

$.post("{% url 'yourUrlName' %}", data, 
    function(response){
        if (response.status == 'ok') {
            // It's all good
            console.log(response)
        } else {
            // Do something with errors
        }
    })
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^yourUrlName/', views.yourUrlName, name='yourUrlName'), #Ajax
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from django.http import JsonResponse


@require_POST
def yourUrlName(request):
    array = request.POST.getlist('pk[]')

    return JsonResponse({
            'status':'ok',
            'array': array,
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `request.GET.getlist('data[]')`

Answer (score 1):

With newer versions of django I was finding that even @YellowCap suggestion of `request.POST.getlist('data[]')` wasn't working for me.

However `dict(request.POST)["data"]` does work. Context here:
https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/1130