# Jquery ajax and Django - post-data arrives malformed

Tags: django, jquery, post

I am making a post via Jquery ajax that looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/sandbox/read_demands/",
    data: {
        "partner_ref": "PH",
        "return_field": ["summary", "details"]
    },
    success: [read_demands_response],
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

I then recieve the data on the server-side with a simple Django view that only prints request.POST into a log. The data then looks like this:

```
{u'return_field[]': [u'summary', u'details'], u'partner_ref': [u'PH']}
```

As you can see, the key 'return_field' has become 'return_field[]' and the value for 'partner_ref' is now a list. What on earth is going on? Am I missing something complected obvious in the jquery post that causes my data to be malformed or is do you think this error comes from somewhere else? I am trying to rule-out different possibilities until I can find the cause of the problem.

This is jquery 1.8.2 and Django 1.4 btw.

Comment: look at `$.param` - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Comment: Thanks, that put me on the right track. Although I am surprised Jquery has such a strange (I am trying hard not to call it something much more unpleasant) default. Defaulting to changing the users formatting... whut. I formatted things like I did for a reason, I don't want my languages to second-guess me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one is just jQuery being jQuery. For reasons best known to themselves, the makers of jQuery believe that PHP is the only way to write server-side applications, and PHP expects fields that have more than one value to have the `[]` suffix - so if you don't provide one, it'll add it. You just have to use it like that in Django.

However, the second one is not an error. It's just how a Django QueryDict works: any value can have multiple items, so they'll always be represented as a list. However, `request.POST['partner_ref']` will correctly give the single value. And in fact to access both values of the other key, you'll need to do `request.POST.getlist('return_field[]')`.

**Edit**: as pointed out in the comments, `$.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;` fixes the jQuery issue.

Comment: That sounds wrong as I have never had these issues with Jquery/Django before, but I will look in to it.

Comment: Aha... I forgot to use $.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;

Comment: Just in case someone else finds this: Using the traditional flag was a bad plan, do like Daniel Roseman said originally instead. 

In many cases it works fine to use the traditional = true, but there are cases where it will not, such as if you must know the type of data you sent in (that data is not always available when using traditional = true). The way jQuery formats it might not be great for Django, but there is a point to it, so might as well use it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with the same problem, and found this related question.

[How to get an array in Django posted via Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101658/how-to-get-an-array-in-django-posted-via-ajax)

The answer recommends using

```
request.GET.getlist('data')
```