# How to receive dictionary in post data python

Tags: python, django, dictionary, parameters, request

I'm trying to send array as a parameter to the api which is using python and `django` framework.

Here's my client side code that is being used to access the `api`:

```java
$.ajax(
    type: 'POST',
    url:    'http://example.com/api/users',
    data:   {user:{name:'Rohit Khatri', age:20, father_name:'S.K'},type:'info'},
    complete: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
);
```

Here's the view where I'm trying to access the request parameters

```py
def get_users(request):
    print(request.POST.get('ids'))
```

and when I try to access `ids` parameter, It gives None.
If anyone has faced the same problem, please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get an array in Django posted via Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12101658/how-to-get-an-array-in-django-posted-via-ajax)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try getting the list as follows:

```
request.POST.getlist('ids[]')
```

**Note**: You will be better off if you send/receive your data as `JSON`. You first need to set the `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers to `application/json` while sending the request and then convert the json to python object using `json.loads`. Example as follows:

#### Javascript/AJAX

```
$.ajax(
    type: 'POST',
    url:    'http://example.com/api/users',
    contentType: 'application/json'
    data:   {ids:[1,2,3,4,5],type:'info'},
    complete: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
);
```

#### Django

```
import json

def get_users(request):
    ids = request.POST.get('ids')
    if ids:
        ids = json.loads(ids)
```

#### Update:

In case you need to use more complicated data such as an object (dictionary) using json will be your best bet and it will work pretty similar to the above example.

#### Javascript/AJAX

```
$.ajax(
    type: 'POST',
    url:    'http://example.com/api/users',
    contentType: 'application/json'
    data:   {ids:{"x":"a", "y":"b", "z":"c"}, type:'info'},
    complete: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
);
```

#### Django

```
import json

def get_users(request):
    ids = request.POST.get('ids')
    if ids:
        ids = json.loads(ids)
```

Comment: I have changed the scenario, actually I want to send dictionary inside a field, not list, can you update your answer for that situation?

Comment: Using the first way. `request.POST.getlist('ids[]')` ?

Comment: @RohitKhatri you should have updated the whole example, there are no `ids` in your AJAX post's data.