# Using array parameters in a Django POST request

Tags: django, datatables

How to get array paramaters posted to django backend?  I am using a jQuery plugin (DataTables Editor) that POSTs a data array parameter like

```
data[id][fieldname][value]
```

How do I get django to accept and use these parameters.

Comment: Click the link below to find the answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12101665/7596326

Comment: I saw and tried the solution in the link `request.POST.getlist('data')` and it returns an empty array even though the data is there.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `request.POST.getlist('data[]')`